# Using the Yule-Walker equation to calibrate an autoregressive model with the method of moments

Tags: self-study, autocorrelation, autoregressive, method-of-moments, discrete-optimization

Consider the following discrete autoregressive $\epsilon_t$, where $\epsilon_t \in (\pm 1 ) \forall \ t \geq 1$. We think of $\epsilon_t$ as the child of a previous sign at time $t-l$, where $l$ is randomly distributed according to unknown distribution $\mathbb{K}(l)$, with $$\sum_{l \geq 1}\mathbb{K}(l) = 1.$$

Once the mother sign is chosen, we have: $$\begin{align} \mathbb{P}(\epsilon_t=\epsilon_{t-l}) &= p \nonumber \\ \mathbb{P}(\epsilon_t=-\epsilon_{t-l}) &= 1-p
\end{align}$$
for some $p < 1$.

The **Yule-Walker** equation for the sign autocorrelation is given by:$$C(l) = (2p-1)\sum_{n \geq1}\mathbb{K}(n)C(l-n),\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ C(0)=1$$

The book I am using suggests the method of moments determine $p$ and $\mathbb{K}(n)$ from empirically observed $C(l)$. I am not quite sure how to proceed from here. My initial thoughts are that once we've estimated $p$, we can use the **Yule-Walker** equation to calculate $\mathbb{K}(n)$ for any n, using the empirical data on C(l). What I am having trouble with is estimating $p$. Usually for the method of moments once fits the expected mean to the empirical mean, but I am not quite sure what means I have to use here.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please include the `self-study` tag. Without that, the question will be "off-topic," and possibly eventually deleted.

Comment: @Carl I have just now. Thank you for letting me know